# Compile-time Matrix Class

Tags: c++, matrix, c++20, constant-expression

Intended as a small project to test out various C++20 features, as well as learn a little bit more about matrices and their uses, I decided to implement a relatively simple matrix class.

After implementing it, I figured out that every single part of it should be able to be done in a compile time context, and re-implemented it (and cleaned it up a little). I'll provide the whole code here, and then highlight some parts where I'm unsure of whether there's a better way. There's a very barebones vector class alongside it for use with the matrix multiplication operator.

```
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <functional>

namespace ctm
{
    typedef std::size_t index_t;
    typedef long double real;

    template <index_t N>
    requires (N > 0)
    struct vector
    {
        std::array<real, N> values;

        constexpr vector(const std::array<real, N>& vals)
        {
            for (index_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                values[i] = vals[i];
            }
        };

        constexpr real dot(const vector<N>& other) const
        {
            real sum = 0.L;

            for (index_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                sum += values[i] * other.values[i];
            }

            return sum;
        };
    };

    template <index_t M, index_t N>
    requires (M > 0 && N > 0)
    struct matrix
    {
        std::array<std::array<real, N>, M> elements = {};

        constexpr matrix() = default;

        constexpr matrix(const std::array<real, M* N>& elems)
        {
            for (index_t i = 0; i < M; ++i)
            {
                for (index_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
                {
                    elements[i][j] = elems[i * N + j];
                }
            }
        };

        constexpr matrix(const std::function<real(index_t, index_t)>& func)
        {
            for (index_t i = 1; i <= M; ++i)
            {
                for (index_t j = 1; j <= N; ++j)
                {
                    elements[i - 1][j - 1] = func(i, j);
                }
            }
        };

        // accessor functions

        // 0-based indexing
        constexpr std::array<real, N>& operator [](index_t index)
        {
            return elements[index];
        };

        // 0-based indexing
        constexpr const std::array<real, N>& operator [](index_t index) const
        {
            return elements[index];
        };

        // 1-based indexing
        constexpr real& operator ()(index_t index_m, index_t index_n)
        {
            if (index_m == 0 || index_n == 0)
            {
                throw std::out_of_range("compound access is 1-indexed");
            }
            else if (index_m > M || index_n > N)
            {
                throw std::out_of_range("compound access out of range");
            }

            return elements[index_m - 1][index_n - 1];
        };

        // 1-based indexing
        constexpr const real& operator ()(index_t index_m, index_t index_n) const
        {
            if (index_m == 0 || index_n == 0)
            {
                throw std::out_of_range("compound access is 1-indexed");
            }
            else if (index_m > M || index_n > N)
            {
                throw std::out_of_range("compound access out of range");
            }

            return elements[index_m - 1][index_n - 1];
        };

        // 1-based indexing
        constexpr vector<N> row(index_t index) const
        {
            if (index == 0)
            {
                throw std::out_of_range{ "row access is 1-indexed " };
            }
            else if (index > M)
            {
                throw std::out_of_range("row access out of range");
            }

            return vector<N>{ elements[index - 1] };
        };

        // 1-based indexing
        constexpr vector<M> column(index_t index) const
        {
            if (index == 0)
            {
                throw std::out_of_range{ "column access is 1-indexed " };
            }
            else if (index > N)
            {
                throw std::out_of_range("column access out of range");
            }

            std::array<real, M> column = {};

            for (index_t j = 0; j < M; ++j)
            {
                column[j] = elements[j][index - 1];
            }

            return vector<M>{ column };
        };

        constexpr matrix<N, M> transpose() const
        {
            matrix<N, M> result = {};

            for (index_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            {
                for (index_t i = 0; i < M; ++i)
                {
                    result.elements[j][i] = elements[i][j];
                }
            }

            return result;
        };

        consteval std::pair<index_t, index_t> size() const
        {
            return { M, N };
        };

        // arithmetic operators

        constexpr matrix& operator +=(const matrix& other)
        {
            for (index_t i = 0; i < M; ++i)
            {
                for (index_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
                {
                    elements[i][j] += other.elements[i][j];
                }
            }

            return *this;
        };

        constexpr matrix& operator -=(const matrix& other)
        {
            for (index_t i = 0; i < M; ++i)
            {
                for (index_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
                {
                    elements[i][j] -= other.elements[i][j];
                }
            }

            return *this;
        };

        constexpr matrix& operator *=(real scalar)
        {
            for (index_t i = 0; i < M; ++i)
            {
                for (index_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
                {
                    elements[i][j] *= scalar;
                }
            }

            return *this;
        };

        constexpr matrix& operator /=(real scalar)
        {
            for (index_t i = 0; i < M; ++i)
            {
                for (index_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
                {
                    elements[i][j] /= scalar;
                }
            }

            return *this;
        };

        constexpr friend matrix operator +(matrix left, const matrix& right)
        {
            return left += right;
        };

        constexpr friend matrix operator -(matrix left, const matrix& right)
        {
            return left -= right;
        };

        constexpr friend matrix operator *(matrix mat, real scalar)
        {
            return mat *= scalar;
        };

        constexpr friend matrix operator *(real scalar, matrix mat)
        {
            return mat *= scalar;
        };

        constexpr friend matrix operator /(matrix mat, real scalar)
        {
            return mat /= scalar;
        };

        template <index_t P>
        constexpr friend matrix<M, P> operator *(const matrix<M, N>& left, const matrix<N, P>& right)
        {
            matrix<M, P> result;

            for (index_t i = 1; i <= M; ++i)
            {
                for (index_t j = 1; j <= P; ++j)
                {
                    vector<N> left_row = left.row(i);
                    vector<N> right_column = right.column(j);
                    result(i, j) = left_row.dot(right_column);
                }
            }

            return result;
        };

        // comparison operator

        constexpr friend bool operator ==(const matrix&, const matrix&) = default;

        // the following functions are only valid for square matrices (M == N)

        // 1-based indexing
        template <index_t m = M, index_t n = N>
        requires (m == n && m > 1)
        constexpr matrix<m - 1, n - 1> first_minor(index_t i, index_t j) const
        {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
            {
                throw std::out_of_range("minor row and column indices are 1-indexed");
            }
            else if (i > M || j > N)
            {
                throw std::out_of_range("minor row and column indices out of range");
            }

            matrix<m - 1, n - 1> minor = {};

            index_t k = 0;
            index_t l = 0;
            for (index_t p = 0; p < m; ++p)
            {
                // skip over the row specified by i
                if (p == i - 1)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                for (index_t q = 0; q < n; ++q)
                {
                    // skip over the column specified by j
                    if (q == j - 1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    minor.elements[k][l] = elements[p][q];

                    ++l;
                }

                ++k;
                l = 0;
            }

            return minor;
        };

        constexpr real trace() const requires(M == N)
        {
            real sum = 0.L;

            for (index_t i = 0, j = 0; i < M; ++i, ++j)
            {
                sum += elements[i][j];
            }

            return sum;
        };

        constexpr real determinant() const requires(M == N && M == 2)
        {
            return elements[0][0] * elements[1][1] - elements[0][1] * elements[1][0];
        };

        constexpr real determinant() const requires(M == N && M > 2)
        {
            real sum = 0.L;
            real parity = 1.L;

            for (index_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            {
                auto submatrix = first_minor(1, j + 1);

                sum += elements[0][j] * parity * submatrix.determinant();
                parity = -parity;
            }

            return sum;
        };

        constexpr bool symmetric() const requires(M == N)
        {
            return *this == transpose();
        };

        constexpr bool skew_symmetric() const requires(M == N)
        {
            return *this == (transpose() *= -1.L);
        };

        // static square matrix creators

        static constexpr matrix<M, N> identity() requires(M == N)
        {
            matrix<M, N> id = {};

            for (index_t i = 0, j = 0; i < M; ++i, ++j)
            {
                id.elements[i][j] = 1.L;
            }

            return id;
        };

        static constexpr matrix<M, N> diagonal(const std::array<real, M>& elems) requires(M == N)
        {
            matrix<M, N> diag = {};

            for (index_t i = 0, j = 0; i < M; ++i, ++j)
            {
                diag.elements[i][j] = elems[i];
            }

            return diag;
        };
    };
};
```

One area that has caused trouble in both of my implementations is the constructor that takes a std::function object. Matrices can have their elements defined by the result of a function that takes the indices of the element as an input, and I wanted to replicate that. Is this the most effective way? I had to make it explicit because a `matrix<M, N>` is able to be converted into a `std::function<real(index_t, index_t)>`, since it defines `real operator ()(index_t, index_t)` for doing 1-indexed matrix access.

Also, is there any way to potentially clean up the `first_minor`'s declaration? I dislike what I have to do to make that one work, but if I try to follow the same pattern as the other functions with a `requires` expression, it complains.

General advice would also be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stylistically, I'd prefer to see `requires`-clauses (like `noexcept`-clauses and trailing return types) indented. That is, where you have

```
template <class T>
requires foo<T>
auto foo()
noexcept(bar)
-> baz
```

I'd prefer to see

```
template<class T>
    requires foo<T>
auto foo()
    noexcept(bar)
    -> baz
```

just to highlight the important parts better.

---

You use `size_t` for your index type, which means you have to special-case `0` in a lot of places. Prefer signed types when dealing with "integers"; unsigned types are better reserved for bitmask manipulations. See ["The '`unsigned` for value range' antipattern"](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/03/13/unsigned-for-value-range/) (2018-03-13). Where you have

```
typedef std::size_t index_t;
[...]
    constexpr real& operator ()(index_t index_m, index_t index_n)
    {
        if (index_m == 0 || index_n == 0)
        {
            throw std::out_of_range("compound access is 1-indexed");
        }
        else if (index_m > M || index_n > N)
        {
            throw std::out_of_range("compound access out of range");
        }
```

I'd rather see

```
using index_t = int;  // actually you don't even need this typedef for anything
[...]
    constexpr real& operator()(int m, int n)
    {
        if (!(1 <= m && m <= M) || !(1 <= n && n <= N)) {
            throw std::out_of_range("compound access out of range");
        }
```

If the user writes `mymatrix(-1, -1)`, you don't want your code silently converting that into `mymatrix(ULONG_MAX, ULONG_MAX)` — that's just confusing!

Also, notice my stylistic cleanups: cuddled braces to save vertical real estate; idiomatic range-comparisons (and btw if you thought we could maybe use C++20 `std::in_range` here, you'd be wrong, it doesn't do what you'd think it does). And writing the names of operators as a single word without whitespace: `operator()` is the name of this function, just as much as `column` is the name of the function below it.

---

```
    constexpr friend matrix operator +(matrix left, const matrix& right)
    {
        return left += right;
    };
```

The trailing semicolon is unnecessary.
It doesn't *really* matter because your `matrix` is trivially copyable and can't benefit from move semantics anyway; but notice that what you're asking for here is

- Make an object named `left`
- Add `right` into `left`, yielding a `matrix&` (that happens to refer to `left`)
- Copy the matrix referred to by that `matrix&` into the return slot

In typical move-friendly code (like, if your `matrix` were a `std::string` or `std::vector`), you'd be much better off saying

- Make an object named `left`
- Add `right` into `left`
- Move (or move-elide) `left` itself into the return slot

which would be spelled

```
    friend constexpr matrix operator+(matrix a, const matrix& b)
    {
        a += b;
        return a;  // implicit move happens here
    }
```

Notice also the "adjective order": just as in English we can have a "lovely little old French whittling knife," in C++ we can have a

```
friend static inline constexpr virtual explicit operator T()
```

(`friend` precedes an otherwise ordinary declaration and is thus the "easiest to strip off"; `static` and `inline` are storage specifiers; `constexpr` doesn't yet affect how the type system sees the entity; `virtual` affects it; and `explicit` is basically the keyword that says "look out, here comes a constructor or conversion operator," going syntactically in place of a normal function's return type.)

EDIT: This is now a blog post. See ["`static constexpr unsigned long` is C++'s 'lovely little old French whittling knife'"](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/04/03/static-constexpr-whittling-knife/) (2021-04-03).

---

```
constexpr matrix(const std::array<real, M* N>& elems)
                                          ^
```

That's a very unfortunate stray space!

---

```
constexpr matrix(const std::function<real(index_t, index_t)>& func)
```

Since you can't call a `std::function` at compile time, there's no point to putting `constexpr` on this constructor. But you knew that. Probably what you should have written instead — in C++20 — is either

```
template<std::invocable<int, int> F>
constexpr matrix(const F& func)
{
```

or

```
template<class F>
    requires std::is_invocable_r<real, const F&, int, int>
constexpr matrix(const F& func)
{
```

The former is prettier. The latter is more rigorous: it checks not only that `F` is invocable, but that `const F&` is invocable (since that's what you'll actually be invoking within the body of the function) and also that the result of that invocation is convertible to `real`. Another option is:

```
template<class F>
constexpr matrix(const F& func)
    requires requires { { func(1,1) } -> std::convertible_to<real>; }
{
```

But that's much ickier-looking syntactically, and ends up checking basically the same thing as the `is_invocable_r` version.

Anyway, the point of all of these is to *avoid type erasure.* You want this constructor to take any callable object?— so *make* it take any callable object! Cut out the middleman. This will also produce better codegen, since the optimizer can probably inline the whole thing and even unroll those loops.

**However.** This probably runs you smack into the usual problem with greedy constructor templates, because guess what type you've made invocable with the signature `real(int, int)`? That's right: `matrix` itself! The solution here is *don't do that*. Combine a normal explicit constructor template with a normal `.at()` member function (just like `vector` and `map` have), while you wait for multi-operand `operator[]` to land in C++2b.

```
template<std::invocable<int, int> F>
constexpr explicit matrix(const F& func) { ... }

constexpr real& at(int i, int j) { ... }
constexpr const real& at(int i, int j) const { ... }
```

Notice that I've marked this constructor `explicit`, in order to prevent implicit conversions from `std::function` to `ctm::matrix`. You want those conversions to be *possible*, but you never want them to happen *implicitly!* As a general rule, every constructor you write should be `explicit`, except for the copy and move constructors (because you *want* copies to happen implicitly), and except for extremely rare cases such as `std::string`'s constructor from `const char *`.

---

You asked about `first_minor`:

```
    template <index_t m = M, index_t n = N>
    requires (m == n && m > 1)
    constexpr matrix<m - 1, n - 1> first_minor(index_t i, index_t j) const
```

At first, I can't even really tell what you're trying to do here. Are those template parameters `m` and `n` actual parameters you expect the caller to pass in? or just copies of `M` and `N` that you're using for metaprogramming? If you're putting metaprogramming into your template parameter list *anyway*, then you should first try to do it in the way we've done it since C++11:

```
    template<class = std::enable_if_t<(M == N) && (M > 1)>
    constexpr matrix<M-1, N-1> first_minor(int i, int j) const
```

However, this still fails when either `M` or `N` is 1, because at that point the return type `matrix<M-1, N-1>` becomes ill-formed (thanks to the requires-clause on `matrix`). So we have to do something sneaky to keep it well-formed. For example:

```
    using SmallerMatrix = matrix<(M > 1) ? M-1 : 1, (N > 1) ? N-1 : 1>;

    constexpr SmallerMatrix first_minor(int i, int j) const
        requires (M == N && M > 1)
```

A more "C++20-ish" clever way to write that would be

```
    constexpr auto first_minor(int i, int j) const
        -> matrix<std::clamp(M-1, 1, M), std::clamp(N-1, 1, N)>
        requires (M == N && M > 1)
```

(As long as you have already taken my advice to use `int` for `index_t`, that is. Otherwise the compiler will complain that `std::clamp` has deduced conflicting types for its template type parameter. All this stuff kind of hangs together as one system. :))

---

Finally, write some unit tests! You could have improved this question by linking to a complete compilable example on Godbolt. That would have made it easier to play around with the `first_minor` metaprogramming, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the great writeup! You've helped me smooth out the code a good bit. Some of the decisions made regarding the interface of the class and the types used are due to matrices only really making sense when they have positive dimensions, but I have decided to change the index type to `std::int_64t` at your suggestion. I believe I'll keep the 1-indexed `operator()`, since part of my goal with this was to have an interface as close as I could get to usual usage of a matrix. Also, making the return type on `first_minor` trailing helped fix the code there. Again, thanks a ton!